# How can I distinguish merge commit or push commit in pre-receive/post-reveice hook

Tags: git, github, jira, githooks

I have a post-receive hook that push a timecard to jira when someone push a commit. But merge commit will trgger it too. So how can I distinguish merge commit or push commit in post-reveice hook?

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#encoding: utf-8

require 'json'

def push_spent_time(msg)
  msg = msg.to_s.rstrip
  msg += " "
  day = msg[/@time.*( \d+d )/, 1]
  hour = msg[/@time.*( \d+h )/, 1]
  min = msg[/@time.*( \d+m )/, 1]
  log = msg[/@time.* \d+[dhm]\s+(.*)$/, 1]
  jira_pattern = /(?<=^|\s|,|\[|\/)([A-Z]{1,32}-[0-9]{1,32})(?=\s|,|\]|\/|$)/
  # Capture the JIRA ID if one is present in the commit message
  jira_id = msg[jira_pattern, 1]

  if msg["@time"]
    day = day.nil? ? 0 : day[/(\d+)d/, 1] 
    hour = hour.nil? ? 0 : hour[/(\d+)h/, 1]
    min = min.nil? ? 0 : min[/(\d+)m/, 1] 
    # Get spent time in seconds
    spent_seconds = day.to_i * 28800 + hour.to_i * 3600 + min.to_i * 60
 
    user = ENV['GL_USERNAME']
    log = log.empty? || log.nil? ? "[#{user}] [EMPTY MESSAGE]." : "[#{user}] #{log}" 
   

    # Push work log
    result = `curl -X POST --url "http://#{ jira_url }:8080/rest/api/2/issue/#{jira_id}/worklog" -u #{ user } -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"comment": "#{log}", "timeSpentSeconds": #{spent_seconds}}'`
    # puts result
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $0
  $rev_old, $rev_new, $ref = STDIN.read.split(" ")
  #p $rev_old, $rev_new, $ref
  
  msg = `git cat-file commit #{ $rev_new } | sed '1,/^$/d' | sed 's/[^ @,.|\/A-Za-z0-9+-]/ /g'`
  push_spent_time(msg)
end
```

When I push a commit just like "com/HAB-001 I did something @time 1d 1h 1m I did some work", then I will get a worklog on jira.Now merge commit can trigger it too and I can't get correct spent time.
I want add some code to get the type of this commit.If the type is merge commit, will not push the timecard again.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "push commit". There are three classes of commit: *root commit*, *ordinary commit*, and *merge commit*. These are commits with 0, 1, and 2-or-more parents. If you want to tell merge from non-merge, count the parents (or test to see if a second parent exists). (It's not clear to me why you're trying to tell these apart here though and in my experience this kind of test usually indicates a bad overall approach to some problem.)

Comment: What I mean is when someone submit a commit and remote push a branch, it will trigger this post-receive hook.In any other case will not trigger it(Like merge the branch on gitlab merge request page).
So how to count the parents with git commands?Or anyother git commands can distinguish them.

Comment: At the Git level, the pre- and post-receive hooks run only for `git push` receiption, not after other Git operations. It's possible that GitLab do something different (so you'll need to check GItLab documentation). To know how many parents there are, use `git rev-parse <commit>^@` (e.g., `git rev-parse refs/heads/master^@` or `for commit in $(git rev-list $old..$new); do git rev-parse ${commit}^@; ...`: the output of this is a list of all parents. Counting them (with `wc -l` for instance) gets you the number. Or, you can just attempt to `git rev-parse <commit>^2`: if that fails, [cont'd]

Comment: [continued] if that fails, there is no second parent. So you'd check the success/fail status. All of this requires writing some scripts, and remember, someone can use `git push --force` to *drop* commits from a branch, or a regular `git push` operation to *add multiple commits*, with some being merges and some not.